# Using one bar graph to display different sets of data

Tags: excel-2010

I was wondering if there was any way that I could use one bar graph in Excel 2010 to display different sets of data at different times.  The way it works in my head is like this: I have a blank bar graph created and from a drop down box I select a value.  Once that value is selected, the data that is tied to that value is displayed on the bar graph.  If I select another value from the drop down list, that data is then displayed on the bar graph, so on and so forth.  Does that even make any sense and is that at all possible?  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a data set in front of me but this might work.

Under chart tools, design, there is a "Select data" button.

Once in here you are given the chance to "selct data source". Click add under "Legend entries (Series). Here you can name and select the other data you wish to show in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complicated answer, but is how I did it with a line graph, and would assume that you could do the same with a bar graph.

1) Set up a pivot table based on the value and data in the spread sheet. Do **not** choose pivot table chart however.

2) (This should be handled automatically when you check the check box if the value is non-numeric) Place the value in the 'Report Filter'.

3) (This should be handled automatically when you check the check box if the data is numeric)Place the data in 'Sigma Values'.

4) link the data to a separate section of cells in the spread sheet.

5) Make sure that selecting new values from the drop down box (which will be automatically provided by the pivot table) Changes the data that is displayed.

6) Select the data. (not the pivot table)

7) Select 'Insert' and the type of chart that you would like to use.

As I said this is kind of complicated, and my explanation is probably not the best. Here is a link to a video that shows this set up for an older value of Excel (2007?) that I used to figure out how to do this in Excel 2010.
http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/flashfiles/chartpivottabletie.html